# C++ base class non-type parameter specialization deduction with auto type specifier fails

Tags: c++

Here's a simplified version of the issue:

Say I have a templated base class with non type parameter, and 2 derived classes with specialization.

```
template <int val>
struct Base {
};

struct Derived1 : public Base<1> {
};

struct Derived2 : public Base<2> {
};

template <int val>
int get(std::unique_ptr<Base<val>> ptr) {
    return val;
}

int main()
{
  // these work
  std::unique_ptr<Base<1>> d1 = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
  std::unique_ptr<Base<2>> d2 = std::make_unique<Derived2>();

  // these fail
//   auto d1 = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
//   auto d2 = std::make_unique<Derived2>();
  std::cout << get(std::move(d1)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << get(std::move(d2)) << std::endl;
}
```

The idea is in the `get()` function, when a derived class unique_ptr is passed in, I want to get the value of the parameter in the base class template.

The `main()` function shows that if I don't use `auto` and explicitly specify the base class type, template would match just fine. However if I switch to `auto`, then type becomes `unique_ptr<DerivedX>` and then it doesn't compile.

http://cpp.sh/2b4tb

If I switch unique_ptr to raw pointer (i.e. `Base<val>*` rather than `unique_ptr<Base<val>>`), things also work. It seems like C++ template doesn't handle type deduction if it's wrapped in another template that gets passed to a function?

Is there something fundamental I'm missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more or less answered your own question already.

When you use `auto` you get a `std::unique_ptr<DerivedX>`. Argument deduction in template only works with exact types. It does not do implicit conversions.

In order for this kind of deduction to work, the compiler would first have to comvert `std::unique_ptr<DerivedX>` to a `std::unique_ptr<Base<val>>`, and after the conversion figure out what `val` is.

One way that could work for you is to give `Base` a static constexpr value that you can access.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <int val>
struct Base {
    static constexpr int my_value = val;
};

struct Derived1 : public Base<1> {
};

struct Derived2 : public Base<2> {
};

template <typename T>
int get(const T& ptr) {
    return (*ptr).my_value;
    // Same thing but written differently
    // return T::element_type::my_value;
}

int main()
{
   auto d1 = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
   auto d2 = std::make_unique<Derived2>();
   std::cout << get(std::move(d1)) << std::endl;
   std::cout << get(std::move(d2)) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with auto. If instead of using auto you just explicitly use std::unique_ptr<Derived1> and std::unique_ptr<Derived2> the problem is still there: http://cpp.sh/242ue Said that, yours is a good workaround to the problem (that is a template resolution problem, not an auto resolution).

Comment: @higlu As my answer states, it's a problem with template argument deduction. The part about `auto` is directly refering to OPs code and only pointing out that the types of `d1` and `d2` differ in the two examples which is the reason why the template deduction fails. I don't really think it can reasonably be misinterpreted as if I'm saying that `auto` is the problem here.

Comment: Thanks @super ! I didn't know I could bake the param info directly through `static constexpr`. TIL. Having said that, while I know template deduction does not do derived-to-base conversion IIRC, I'm not sure why that broke for `unique_ptr` (not exactly but you get the point)  but worked if I change get() to take raw pointer (which should also be derived-to-base conversion).

Comment: @NSF Have a look at section `Deduction from function call`, at the very bottom just before `Non-deduced context` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). The pointer conversion is allowed apparently.